# Time spend running program

Tags: c#, performance, time

How I print in a textbox or at the output the time that the program spend running?

I want it to be displayed into a for-loop, to get how much time each for-loop needs.

Comment: Take a look at this article: [Timing C# function performance with the Stopwatch class](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/timing-function-performance-stopwatch-class/)

Comment: Well, you set the timer, run the program, stop the timer, and type the time in a textbox. Easy! To be more serious, try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx and `.Subtract()`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could try:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
for (.......)
{
}
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - dt;
textbox1.Text = ts.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
```

or (according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)) if you need better resolution

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
for (.......)
{
}
stopWatch.Stop();
textbox1.Text = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
```

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) documentation specifically advises **against** using the DateTime class for benchmarking purposes.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: yes, you're right. I edited my post including both solutions. Thanks

Comment: You can use `stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds` directly and get rid of intermediate TimeSpan conversions

Comment: @Marco : yep but also you've skipped some code for string formatting. They are usign TimeSpan to output formatted date time not only milliseconds, second MSDN example which outputs Milliseconds does not use TimeSpan

Answer (score 16):

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

for()
{
 // ..
}

watch.Stop();

// Format 00:00:02.0001008
string elapsed = watch.Elapsed.ToString();     

// Milliseconds like 2000 for 2 seconds
string elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(); 

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(elapsed);
```

Comment: +1 for you, because your answer was the first and it's correct!!

Answer (score 0):

something like this: ?

```
DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;

//... processing ...

DateTime end = DateTime.UtcNow;

Syste.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((end - start).ToString());
```

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) documentation specifically advises **against** using the DateTime class for benchmarking purposes.

Comment: sure I know there are finer timers, this is good if you want to see seconds or minutes... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could store the current DateTime on application startup, then create a timer that fires every second. When it fires you get the current DateTime, subtract them to get the TimeSpan and use that to fill your textbox.

Comment: Wouldn't that just count the seconds?

Comment: You update the input box every second, not measure the timespan.

Answer (score 0):

Add these Two Lines- Between your For loop or between the code where you want to test the functinality speed.

```
 Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

  --your code

 Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
```

Comment: This won't be accurate because you'll be measuring not just how long the code took to execute but how long it took to turn a DateTime into a string + run the code.  Granted if the code runs in something on the order of minutes a few milliseconds will be insignificant, but for shorter running could it could make a difference.

Comment: @Romanarmy , you are correct, if it kind of time critical Nuclear project.. And as you know most of the projects we develop everyday are Nuclear Web Applications.

Comment: no, but we've all written code that executes in a tight loop, and making it less efficient means poor user experience because the UI locks up for a second every time a user clicks a button.