# Change colors with time gap in wpf

Tags: wpf

I have 4 stackpanels, and a textbox that user can enter time in and a button.
How can I ensure the 4 boxes colors change (to some random ones) with the time gap of given input on clicking start button.
So its like, if the input is 1 second, first box changes to yellow then after 1s second box changes its color to red and so on until 4th box.
Is there any efficient and faster way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for:

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Background="{Binding Brush1}" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <StackPanel Background="{Binding Brush2}" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <StackPanel Background="{Binding Brush3}" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <StackPanel Background="{Binding Brush4}" Grid.Row="3"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding Number}"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="5" Content="Start" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Code behind (*with `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented*):

```
    public DispatcherTimer DispatcherTimer { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    private int _counter;

    Brush _b1;
    public Brush Brush1
    {
        get
        {
            return _b1;
        }
        set
        {
            _b1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Brush1");
        }
    }

    Brush _b2;
    public Brush Brush2
    {
        get
        {
            return _b2;
        }
        set
        {
            _b2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Brush2");
        }
    }

    Brush _b3;
    public Brush Brush3
    {
        get
        {
            return _b3;
        }
        set
        {
            _b3 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Brush3");
        }
    }

    Brush _b4;
    public Brush Brush4
    {
        get
        {
            return _b4;
        }
        set
        {
            _b4 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Brush4");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        DispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        DispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        Number = 1;
    }

    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (_counter)
        {
            case 2:
                Brush2 = PickRandomBrush();
                _counter++;
                break;
            case 3:
                Brush3 = PickRandomBrush();
                _counter++;
                break;
            case 4:
                Brush4 = PickRandomBrush();
                DispatcherTimer.Stop();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Brush1 = PickRandomBrush();
        _counter = 2;

        DispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, Number);
        DispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    private Brush PickRandomBrush()
    {
        Brush result = Brushes.Transparent;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Type brushesType = typeof(Brushes);
        PropertyInfo[] properties = brushesType.GetProperties();
        int random = rnd.Next(properties.Length);
        result = (Brush)properties[random].GetValue(null, null);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This is good. So, I changed the timer to take milliseconds, Number property to double.
When I input the number 0.1 (ms), or lesser than that - to my eyes it seems like the same time but how do we ensure that it is really acting on the number as you give the input ?

Comment: You can use `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch` to log elapsed time after each color change. You may want to look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7836552/1648849) for a simple example.